# How to change this app to disable input from command line?

Tags: error-handling, segmentation-fault, coredump, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

This is the Original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <sys/select.h>
#endif

#include <sphinxbase/err.h>
#include <sphinxbase/ad.h>

#include "pocketsphinx.h"

static const arg_t cont_args_def[] = {
    POCKETSPHINX_OPTIONS,
    /* Argument file. */
    {"-argfile",
     ARG_STRING,
     NULL,
     "Argument file giving extra arguments."},
    {"-adcdev",
     ARG_STRING,
     NULL,
     "Name of audio device to use for input."},
    {"-infile",
     ARG_STRING,
     NULL,
     "Audio file to transcribe."},
    {"-inmic",
     ARG_BOOLEAN,
     "no",
     "Transcribe audio from microphone."},
    {"-time",
     ARG_BOOLEAN,
     "no",
     "Print word times in file transcription."},
    CMDLN_EMPTY_OPTION
};

static ps_decoder_t *ps;
static cmd_ln_t *config;
static FILE *rawfd;

static void
print_word_times()
{
    int frame_rate = cmd_ln_int32_r(config, "-frate");
    ps_seg_t *iter = ps_seg_iter(ps);
    while (iter != NULL) {
        int32 sf, ef, pprob;
        float conf;

        ps_seg_frames(iter, &sf, &ef);
        pprob = ps_seg_prob(iter, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        conf = logmath_exp(ps_get_logmath(ps), pprob);
        printf("%s %.3f %.3f %f\n", ps_seg_word(iter), ((float)sf / frame_rate),
               ((float) ef / frame_rate), conf);
        iter = ps_seg_next(iter);
    }
}

static int
check_wav_header(char *header, int expected_sr)
{
    int sr;

    if (header[34] != 0x10) {
        E_ERROR("Input audio file has [%d] bits per sample instead of 16\n", header[34]);
        return 0;
    }
    if (header[20] != 0x1) {
        E_ERROR("Input audio file has compression [%d] and not required PCM\n", header[20]);
        return 0;
    }
    if (header[22] != 0x1) {
        E_ERROR("Input audio file has [%d] channels, expected single channel mono\n", header[22]);
        return 0;
    }
    sr = ((header[24] & 0xFF) | ((header[25] & 0xFF) << 8) | ((header[26] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((header[27] & 0xFF) << 24));
    if (sr != expected_sr) {
        E_ERROR("Input audio file has sample rate [%d], but decoder expects [%d]\n", sr, expected_sr);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

/*
 * Continuous recognition from a file
 */
static void
recognize_from_file()
{
    int16 adbuf[2048];
    const char *fname;
    const char *hyp;
    int32 k;
    uint8 utt_started, in_speech;
    int32 print_times = cmd_ln_boolean_r(config, "-time");

    fname = cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-infile");
    if ((rawfd = fopen(fname, "rb")) == NULL) {
        E_FATAL_SYSTEM("Failed to open file '%s' for reading",
                       fname);
    }

    if (strlen(fname) > 4 && strcmp(fname + strlen(fname) - 4, ".wav") == 0) {
        char waveheader[44];
    fread(waveheader, 1, 44, rawfd);
    if (!check_wav_header(waveheader, (int)cmd_ln_float32_r(config, "-samprate")))
            E_FATAL("Failed to process file '%s' due to format mismatch.\n", fname);
    }

    if (strlen(fname) > 4 && strcmp(fname + strlen(fname) - 4, ".mp3") == 0) {
    E_FATAL("Can not decode mp3 files, convert input file to WAV 16kHz 16-bit mono before decoding.\n");
    }

    ps_start_utt(ps);
    utt_started = FALSE;

    while ((k = fread(adbuf, sizeof(int16), 2048, rawfd)) > 0) {
        ps_process_raw(ps, adbuf, k, FALSE, FALSE);
        in_speech = ps_get_in_speech(ps);
        if (in_speech && !utt_started) {
            utt_started = TRUE;
        } 
        if (!in_speech && utt_started) {
            ps_end_utt(ps);
            hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL);
            if (hyp != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", hyp);
            if (print_times)
            print_word_times();
            fflush(stdout);

            ps_start_utt(ps);
            utt_started = FALSE;
        }
    }
    ps_end_utt(ps);
    if (utt_started) {
        hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL);
        if (hyp != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", hyp);
            if (print_times) {
            print_word_times();
        }
    }
    }

    fclose(rawfd);
}

/* Sleep for specified msec */
static void
sleep_msec(int32 ms)
{
#if (defined(_WIN32) && !defined(GNUWINCE)) || defined(_WIN32_WCE)
    Sleep(ms);
#else
    /* ------------------- Unix ------------------ */
    struct timeval tmo;

    tmo.tv_sec = 0;
    tmo.tv_usec = ms * 1000;

    select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tmo);
#endif
}

/*
 * Main utterance processing loop:
 *     for (;;) {
 *        start utterance and wait for speech to process
 *        decoding till end-of-utterance silence will be detected
 *        print utterance result;
 *     }
 */
static void
recognize_from_microphone()
{
    ad_rec_t *ad;
    int16 adbuf[2048];
    uint8 utt_started, in_speech;
    int32 k;
    char const *hyp;

    if ((ad = ad_open_dev(cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-adcdev"),
                          (int) cmd_ln_float32_r(config,
                                                 "-samprate"))) == NULL)
        E_FATAL("Failed to open audio device\n");
    if (ad_start_rec(ad) < 0)
        E_FATAL("Failed to start recording\n");

    if (ps_start_utt(ps) < 0)
        E_FATAL("Failed to start utterance\n");
    utt_started = FALSE;
    E_INFO("Ready....\n");

    for (;;) {
        if ((k = ad_read(ad, adbuf, 2048)) < 0)
            E_FATAL("Failed to read audio\n");
        ps_process_raw(ps, adbuf, k, FALSE, FALSE);
        in_speech = ps_get_in_speech(ps);
        if (in_speech && !utt_started) {
            utt_started = TRUE;
            E_INFO("Listening...\n");
        }
        if (!in_speech && utt_started) {
            /* speech -> silence transition, time to start new utterance  */
            ps_end_utt(ps);
            hyp = ps_get_hyp(ps, NULL );
            if (hyp != NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", hyp);
                fflush(stdout);
            }

            if (ps_start_utt(ps) < 0)
                E_FATAL("Failed to start utterance\n");
            utt_started = FALSE;
            E_INFO("Ready....\n");
        }
        sleep_msec(100);
    }
    ad_close(ad);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char const *cfg;

    config = cmd_ln_parse_r(NULL, cont_args_def, argc, argv, TRUE);

    /* Handle argument file as -argfile. */
    if (config && (cfg = cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-argfile")) != NULL) {
        config = cmd_ln_parse_file_r(config, cont_args_def, cfg, FALSE);
    }

    if (config == NULL || (cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-infile") == NULL && cmd_ln_boolean_r(config, "-inmic") == FALSE)) {
    E_INFO("Specify '-infile <file.wav>' to recognize from file or '-inmic yes' to recognize from microphone.\n");
        cmd_ln_free_r(config);
    return 1;
    }

    ps_default_search_args(config);
    ps = ps_init(config);
    if (ps == NULL) {
        cmd_ln_free_r(config);
        return 1;
    }

    E_INFO("%s COMPILED ON: %s, AT: %s\n\n", argv[0], __DATE__, __TIME__);

    if (cmd_ln_str_r(config, "-infile") != NULL) {
        recognize_from_file();
    } else if (cmd_ln_boolean_r(config, "-inmic")) {
        recognize_from_microphone();
    }

    ps_free(ps);
    cmd_ln_free_r(config);

    return 0;
}

#if defined(_WIN32_WCE)
#pragma comment(linker,"/entry:mainWCRTStartup")
#include <windows.h>
//Windows Mobile has the Unicode main only
int
wmain(int32 argc, wchar_t * wargv[])
{
    char **argv;
    size_t wlen;
    size_t len;
    int i;

    argv = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        wlen = lstrlenW(wargv[i]);
        len = wcstombs(NULL, wargv[i], wlen);
        argv[i] = malloc(len + 1);
        wcstombs(argv[i], wargv[i], wlen);
    }

    //assuming ASCII parameters
    return main(argc, argv);
}
#endif
```

I can compile it by this command:

```
g++ -o output continuous.cpp         -DMODELDIR=\"`pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx`\"     `pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase`
```

And run it by this command : `output -inmic yes` .

But I like to convert the code as it has no need to get `inmic yes` and it automatically starts the program from microphone. But I got `segmentation fault(core dumped)` error when I changed these parts:

```
static const arg_t cont_args_def= {"-inmic",
     ARG_BOOLEAN,
     "no",
     "Transcribe audio from microphone."};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    config = cmd_ln_parse_r(NULL, cont_args_def, argc, argv, TRUE);

 if (cmd_ln_boolean_r(config, "-inmic")) {
        recognize_from_microphone();
    }



   // recognize_from_microphone();
    ps_free(ps);
    cmd_ln_free_r(config);



    return 0;

}
```

I searched a lot and red the documentation but couldn't understand what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change the last argument passed to `cmd_ln_parse_r` from `TRUE` to `FALSE`.
It has something to do with strict checking.
I figured this out by reading the source code for cmd_ln.c in the sphinxbase code.

I also changed the boolean value for `-inmic` in `cont_args_def` from "no" to "yes".